PL/SQL function to detect a one way character change between 2 strings
I want to write a PL/SQL function with 4 arguments: SEARCH_STRING, CHECK_STRING, SEARCH_CHAR and CHECK_CHAR
where the function will check the SEARCH_STRING against the CHECK_STRING and detect whether the only difference between the 2 strings is that some CHECK_CHAR in CHECK_STRING got changed to SEARCH_CHAR (and everything other than that is the same).
Example 1:
SEARCH_STRING: 'AA BB AA BAC' 
CHECK_STRING: 'AA CC AA BAC'
SEARCH_CHAR: 'B'
CHECK_CHAR: 'C'

This would return TRUE/1 since 2 'C' characters are changed to 'B' and the else is the same.
Example 2:
SEARCH_STRING: 'NGUYEN THI THU THUY THI'
CHECK_STRING: 'NGUYEN THU THU THUY THI'
SEARCH_CHAR: 'I'
CHECK_CHAR: 'U'

This would return TRUE/1 since 1 'U' character is changed to 'I' and everything else is the same.
I've approached this using a loop, which takes the index positions of all of the SEARCH_CHAR in SEARCH_STRING and look in CHECK_STRING at those positions to see if there's any CHECK_CHAR. However the loop would affect query performance so I am looking for a more efficient way to do this.
Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

use a replace function on your search string and compare result to check string.

There is not an (obvious) simple function that will solve it and you (probably) need to loop through the string and compare characters:
CREATE FUNCTION check_translation(
  SEARCH_STRING VARCHAR2,
  CHECK_STRING  VARCHAR2,
  SEARCH_CHAR   VARCHAR2,
  CHECK_CHAR    VARCHAR2
) RETURN NUMBER
IS
  v_sch CHAR(1);
  v_cch CHAR(1);
BEGIN
  IF LENGTH(search_string) = LENGTH(check_string) THEN
    FOR i IN 1 .. LENGTH(search_string) LOOP
      v_sch := SUBSTR(search_string, i, 1);
      v_cch := SUBSTR(check_string, i, 1);
      IF v_sch != v_cch AND (v_sch != search_char OR v_cch != check_char) THEN
        RETURN 0;
      END IF;
    END LOOP;
    RETURN 1;
  END IF;
  RETURN 0;
END;
/

Then:
WITH data (search_string, check_string, search_char, check_char) AS (
  SELECT 'AA BB AA BAC', 'AA CC AA BAC', 'B', 'C' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'AA BB AA BAC', 'AA CC AA BAC', 'C', 'B' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'NGUYEN THI THU THUY THI', 'NGUYEN THU THU THUY THI', 'I', 'U' FROM DUAL
)
SELECT search_string AS sstr,
       check_string AS cstr,
       search_char AS sch,
       check_char AS cch,
       check_translation(
         search_string,
         check_string,
         search_char,
         check_char
       ) AS result
FROM   data;

Outputs:



SSTR
CSTR
SCH
CCH
RESULT




AA BB AA BAC
AA CC AA BAC
B
C
1


AA BB AA BAC
AA CC AA BAC
C
B
0


NGUYEN THI THU THUY THI
NGUYEN THU THU THUY THI
I
U
1



fiddle

@DucDo Updated.

The check character in check_string is allowed to - but doesn't have to - change to the search_char.
We can check this with regular expressions: We derive the pattern from the resulting search_string by mainly replacing the resulted 'B' to '[CB]', because the source for a B must be either a B or a C. We then add '^' for the beginning and '$' for the end of the string in order to compare complete strings.
select check_string, search_string,
  CASE WHEN REGEXP_LIKE(check_string, '^' || REPLACE(search_string, search_char, '[' || search_char || check_char || ']') || '$') THEN
    'okay'
  ELSE
    'faulty'
  END as status
from mytable;

Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/EYbKoqMG
You can of course convert this into a PL/SQL function if you want to.
